# Is it possible to get a reference to the gameObject from an interface?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've implemented an interface `IVehicle` for all vehicles in my game and would like to be able to get a reference to the `gameObject` whose script is attached to without using a `gameObject` property. Is this possible?

Something like:

```
IVehicle vehicle = GameObject.FindObjectOfType(typeof(IVehicle));
GameObject vehicleGO = vehicle.gameObject;
```

Comment: If the implementation of `IVehicle` has a reference to the `gameObject` then yes, otherwise no.

Comment: You can add a GameObject property or method to the interface contract

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, there is a very easy solution. just place

```
GameObject gameObject { get ; }
```

as part of your interface - all MonoBehaviours implement it, no extra steps needed. I add it to almost all my interfaces in Unity, it costs nothing and helps a lot

Answer (score 5):

It is possible and an extra variable is *not* required. It's worth noting that you can't retrieve an interface in the scene with `FindObjectOfType` like you did in your question. You can only use `FindObjectOfType` with `MonoBehaviour`.

Get your interface:

```
using System.Linq;

IVehicle[] vehicles = FindObjectsOfType<MonoBehaviour>().OfType<IVehicle>().ToArray();
```

Cast to `MonoBehaviour` then you now can now access the GameObject that is linked with it

```
for (int i = 0; i < vehicles.Length; i++)
    GameObject vehicleGO = ((MonoBehaviour)vehicles[i]).gameObject;
```

---

Also, if you know the script name that implements the interface, no need to cast to `MonoBehaviour`. You can just cast to that script. Let's say the script that implements the `IVehicle` interface is named `Car`, you would just do something like this:

```
GameObject vehicleGO = ((Car)vehicles[i]).gameObject;
```

Comment: Great answer! I chose a different one as the correct answer for it's simplicity, although yours is certainly just as valid. In truth, I had to use both answers to solve my problem. It's also worth noting that the `OfType<T>()` method you're using requires the include `using system.Linq`.